# How to subtract two identical dataframes in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have got two identical dataframes in pandas/python (a and b) only values are different:

a:

```
date       a1 a2 a3
01.01.2020 2  2  2
02.01.2020 3  3  3
03.01.2020 4  4  4
```

b:

```
date       a1 a2 a3
01.01.2020 1  1  1
01.01.2020 2  2  2
01.01.2020 3  3  3
```

I need a - b and expect to see result c:

```
date       a1 a2 a3
01.01.2020 1  1  1
01.01.2020 1  1  1
01.01.2020 1  1  1
```

a - b does not work and I cannot figure out how. Would you please help me? Thanks!

Comment: Are the dates identical as well?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that dates in both dataframes are identical,
you can use `df.sub`:

```
df = a.set_index('date').sub(b.set_index('date')).reset_index()
```

Output:

```
         date  a1  a2  a3
0  01.01.2020   1   1   1
1  01.01.2020   1   1   1
2  01.01.2020   1   1   1
```

Answer (score 2):

You can `set_index`:

```
new_df = (a.set_index('date') - b.set_index('date')).reset_index()
```

However, that only works if your dates are identical between the two dataframes and different within each.

In the other case (as shown in your sample data) you can do:

```
c = b.copy()
c.iloc[:,1:] = a.iloc[:, 1:] - b.iloc[:,1:]
```

Comment: Thanks, but isn't' there an error in expression? There should be a minus "-" sign between variable "a" and "b", right? `c.iloc[:,1:] = a.iloc[:, 1:] - b.iloc[:,1:]`

Answer (score 0):

Try using `df1.subtract(df2)`. Simple and elegant.

Comment: this is essentially the same as `a-b` which doesn't work as stated by OP.